# How to add comments to a Django post

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

After adding this code to admin.py, I was expecting to see a Comments section under Blog on the Site Administration Page. To the best of my knowledge, I have run the appropriate migrations. I have looked at posts on Stack Overflow but still have not figured out the answer.

```
from django.contrib import admin

#register our models so they show up on our admin page
from .models import Post, Comment  
admin.site.register(Post)

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'body', 'post', 'created_on', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created_on')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
    actions = ['approve_comments']

    def approve_comments(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the current user permissions and check if you have the permission for the Comment Model.

Also you need to specify that your are using CommentAdmin for Comment model during registration ie

```
admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```